# R data.table: New data table with named columns and drop the rest

Tags: r, data.table

I want to do something very simple but so far I have failed to do it in one command. I want to create a new data table by applying a function to some columns of an existing one while giving them a name and droppinh the rest.
Let's see a minimal example:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(A = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'),
                B = c(1  , 2  , 3  , 4  , 5  ),
                C = c(10 , 20 , 30 , 40 , 50))
dt
A   B   C
a   1   10
a   2   20
a   3   30
b   4   40
b   5   50
```

For a single column, we can do:

```
dt1 = dt[, .(totalB = sum(B)), by=A]
dt1
A   totalB
a   6
b   9
```

For more than 1 columns, we can do:

```
dt2 = dt[, .(totalB = sum(B), totalC = sum(C)), by=A]
dt2
A   totalB   totalC
a   6        60
b   9        90
```

But if the columns are many that's not the best practice. So I guess we should go with `lapply` like that:

```
dt3 = dt[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = A]
dt3
A   B   C
a   6   60
b   9   90
```

That creates the table but without the names. So we can add them:

```
names = c("totalA", "totalB")
dt4 = dt[, c("totalA", "totalB") := lapply(.SD, sum), by = A ]
dt4
A   B   C   totalA  totalB
a   1   10  6   60
a   2   20  6   60
a   3   30  6   60
b   4   40  9   90
b   5   50  9   90
```

But now the columns remained. How can we prevent that? Also note that in my actual problem I use a subset of the columns, via SDcols, which I didn't include here for simplicity.

EDIT: My desired output is the same as `dt2` but I don't want to write down all columns.

Comment: Why not just selecting the relevant columns in your dt4 creation, you can add an additional `[]` and select the two columns, you're interested in.

Comment: @hannes101 I am actually intested in plenty of columns though. So not that simple. Plus, ituitively, there should be a way to do what I want given that it's so close.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like below?

```
dt[, setNames(lapply(.SD, sum), paste0("total", names(.SD))), A]
```

- Output

```
   A totalB totalC
1: a      6     60
2: b      9     90
```

Comment: Sorry but no. I think that's actually the same as my `dt4`.  Also, I  will not be using totalB etc so I definitely want the names vector.

Comment: @cgss What's your desired output? Please show an example

Comment: My desired output is the same as dt2 but if I have like 10 columns writing `.(name1 = sum(col1), ... , name10=sum(col10)) looks kinda bad. I will edit the question to add this.

Comment: Your update works in thw mwe. It also works with my `names` variable, instead of the `paste` function. Strangely enough, it results in the following error in my actual project:
`setnames(lapply(.SD, sum), names): x is not a data.table or data.frame` Clearly, it is a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `setnames`.  Create a vector of column names that we want to apply the function other than the grouping variable ('nm1'), grouped by 'A', get the `sum`, and use `setnames` with `old` and `new` specified

```
nm1 <- setdiff(names(dt), "A")
setnames(dt[, lapply(.SD, sum), A], nm1, paste0('total', nm1))[]
```